# How to initialize a single element from an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, initialization, structure

I am working with a code which reads many files and stores the count of keywords in it. A part of the code is as follows:

```
struct files
{
    struct keyword
    {
        char keyname[10];
        int count;
    }key[32];            //for 32 keywords in C
}file[10];
```

How can I initialize the keyword structure for all the 10 files as `{"void",0,"int",0,.....etc}` ?
Is there a method by which I can initialize all the 10 files in a loop by initializing each structure element at a time?

Comment: I'm puzzled: C99 has 37 keywords (auto
break
case
char
const
continue
default
do
double
else
enum
extern
float
for
goto
if
inline
int
long
register
restrict
return
short
signed
sizeof
static
struct
switch
typedef
union
unsigned
void
volatile
while
_Bool
_Complex
_Imaginary) and C11 has 7 more (_Alignas
_Alignof 
_Atomic 
_Generic 
_Noreturn 
_Static_assert 
_Thread_local).  How old a version of C are you using that only has 32 keywords?  I suppose that must be C89/90; that omitted inline, restrict and the keywords starting with underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified @Gopi's code,

```
char keywords[32][]={"void","int" ......}; //Holds all the needed keywords,fill upto last desired keyword
for(j=0;j<32;j++)  //takes each file structure (10 file structure)
{
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       //updates the 32 keynames and its count
       strcpy(file[i].key[j].keyname,keywords[j]); 
       file[i].key[j].count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

10 files can be initialized using a loop as shown below.

```
 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<32;j++)
       {
          strcpy(file[i].key[j].keyname,"key"); /* scan the value from user and input */
          file[i].key[j].count = 0;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This compile with gcc 4.4 --

```
int main() {
struct keyword
    {
        char keyname[5];
        int count;
    };
struct keyword files[4] = { {"void",0},{"int",4},{"long",8},{"utyp",12} };
  return 0;
}
```

Guess it depends on the compiler you are using.

Comment: We already tried this but didnt work...Thank you for your response! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using standard C, there isn't a way to avoid a loop such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    file[i] = (struct files){ { { "auto", 0 }, { "break", 0 },
                  { "case", 0 }, { "char", 0 }, { "const", 0 },
                  { "continue", 0 }, { "default", 0 }, { "do", 0 },
                  { "double", 0 }, { "else", 0 }, { "enum", 0 },
                  { "extern", 0 }, { "float", 0 }, { "for", 0 },
                  { "goto", 0 }, { "if", 0 }, { "int", 0 },
                  { "long", 0 }, { "register", 0 }, { "return", 0 },
                  { "short", 0 }, { "signed", 0 }, { "sizeof", 0 },
                  { "static", 0 }, { "struct", 0 }, { "switch", 0 },
                  { "typedef", 0 }, { "union", 0 }, { "unsigned", 0 },
                  { "void", 0 }, { "volatile", 0 }, { "while", 0 },
                } };
```

This uses a C99 compound literal to initialize each row.

GCC has an extension that allows you to do it all in initializers (where you must put a space before the ellipsis to avoid problems with the 'maximal munch' rule):

```
struct files file[10] = { [0 ... 9] = { { { "auto", 0 }, { "break", 0 },
                  { "case", 0 }, { "char", 0 }, { "const", 0 },
                  { "continue", 0 }, { "default", 0 }, { "do", 0 },
                  { "double", 0 }, { "else", 0 }, { "enum", 0 },
                  { "extern", 0 }, { "float", 0 }, { "for", 0 },
                  { "goto", 0 }, { "if", 0 }, { "int", 0 },
                  { "long", 0 }, { "register", 0 }, { "return", 0 },
                  { "short", 0 }, { "signed", 0 }, { "sizeof", 0 },
                  { "static", 0 }, { "struct", 0 }, { "switch", 0 },
                  { "typedef", 0 }, { "union", 0 }, { "unsigned", 0 },
                  { "void", 0 }, { "volatile", 0 }, { "while", 0 },
              } } };
```